# Item doesn't display in the cart

Tags: python, flask

So I am trying to display the item in the basket that I have added, but nothing is displaying.

```
@phones.route("/cartt")
def shopping_cart():
total_price = 0
if "cart" not in session:
    flash("There is nothing in your cart.")
    return render_template("phones/cart.html", display_cart = {}, total = 0)
else:
    items = [j for i in session["cart"] for j in i]
    dict_of_phones = {}
    phone_by_id = None

    for item in items:
        phone = get_phone_by_id(item)
        print(phone.id)
        total_price += phone.price
        dict_of_phones = phone
    return render_template('phones/cart.html', display_cart = dict_of_phones, total = total_price)
```

html:

```
   {% for phone in dict_of_phones %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{phone.model}}</td>
        <td>{{phone.year}}</td>
        <td>${{ "%.2f" % phone.price}}</td>
        <td>${{ "%.2f" % phone.price}}</td></tr>    
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong variable name in your template. It should be display_cart instead of dict_of_phones. See below:

```
{% for phone in display_cart %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{phone.model}}</td>
        <td>{{phone.year}}</td>
        <td>${{ "%.2f" % phone.price}}</td>
        <td>${{ "%.2f" % phone.price}}</td>
    </tr>    
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: when i changed the variable name, I got an error: `TypeError: 'Phone' object is not iterable`

Comment: That's because you need to make dict_of_phone a list of whatever it is you need to display in your cart. And each of those phone also need to have properties that you're using in your template such as phone.model, phone.year, etc. Naming something dict_of_phone doesn't make it a dict, you must make it a dict before passing it to the template. Also, accessing a dict in the template the way you're doing it is not correct. It should be phone['model'] or phone['year']

Answer (score 0):

I would pass a ***list of phones into your template*** as opposed to dictionary of phones. Also, your `dict_of_phones` is *only set to the last value of your phone items* since you're overriding its value every time with `dict_of_phones = phone`. So `dict_of_phones` is really just a *single phone item given by the last item in items*: `phone = get_phone_by_id(item)`. Maybe you could modify your code to create a phone list? Then pass this list into your `jinja2` template, something along the lines of:

```
@phones.route("/cartt")
def shopping_cart():
total_price = 0
if "cart" not in session:
    flash("There is nothing in your cart.")
    return render_template("phones/cart.html", display_cart = {}, total = 0)
else:
    # Assuming items is correct, looks off
    items = [j for i in session["cart"] for j in i]
    phones = []

    for item in items:
        phone = get_phone_by_id(item)
        print(phone.id)
        # assuming phone has id,model,year, and price attributes
        phones.append[phone]
        # note total_price of your cart not currently being used in your template
        total_price += phone.price
    return render_template('phones/cart.html', display_cart=phones, total = total_price)
```

Then within your template you can do something along the lines of:

```
{% for phone in display_cart %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{phone.model}}</td>
        <td>{{phone.year}}</td>
        <td>${{ "%.2f" % phone.price}}</td>
        <td>${{ "%.2f" % phone.price}}</td>
    </tr>    
{% endfor %}
```

Hopefully that helps!